# deque with unique_ptr of thread wrapper

Tags: c++, multithreading, embedded-linux

I'm trying to compile this for an embedded project, but it keeps failing to compile. The code compiles properly with clang on mac.
The example basically adds 2 threads to a deque container, joins them and deletes them from the container. **UPDATED**

```
class th {
    public:
        void func() {
            sleep(3);
            *this->progress = 100;
        }

        th(int* prog) :
            progress(prog), 
            m_thread(std::thread(&th::func, this)) {};

        th(th const& other) = delete;
        th(th && other) = default;
        th& operator=(th const& other) = delete;
        th& operator=(th &&) = default;

        void join() { m_thread.join(); }
        int *progress;

    private:
        std::thread m_thread;
};

int main(void) {

        std::vector<int> progress;
        progress.push_back(-1);
        progress.push_back(-1);

        std::deque<std::unique_ptr<th>> deq;

        std::cout << "progress[0]:" << progress[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "progress[1]:" << progress[1] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "executing threads..." << std::endl;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            deq.push_back(std::unique_ptr<th>(new th(&progress[i])));
        }

        while(true) {
            std::cout << "SIZE:" << deq.size() << std::endl;

            if(deq.size() == 0)
                break;

            for (std::deque<std::unique_ptr<th>>::iterator it = deq.begin(); it != deq.end(); it++) {
                //std::cout << (*it)->progress << std::endl;
                if(*((*it)->progress) == 100) {
                    std::cout << "JOIN & DELETE" << std::endl;
                    (*it)->join();
                    deq.erase(it);
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "STILL RUNNING" << std::endl;
                }
                    //std::cout << *((*it)->progress) << std::endl;
            }
            sleep(1);
        }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**UPDATED** - the compiler message:

```
In file included from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/concept_check.h:55:0,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/move.h:35,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_pair.h:60,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/ios:41,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/ostream:40,
                 from /ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/iostream:40,
                 from /home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:1:
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>::__constraints() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]':
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_deque.h:717:1:   instantiated from 'std::deque<std::unique_ptr<th> >'
/home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:55:35:   instantiated from here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:207:7: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:203:28: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:208:19: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:204:7: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>::__const_constraints(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]':
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:205:7:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>::__constraints() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_deque.h:717:1:   instantiated from 'std::deque<std::unique_ptr<th> >'
/home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:55:35:   instantiated from here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:207:7: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:208:28: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:208:19: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:209:7: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::_Mutable_BidirectionalIteratorConcept<_Tp>::__constraints() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>*]':
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:57:50:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::__function_requires() [with _Concept = __gnu_cxx::_Mutable_BidirectionalIteratorConcept<std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:673:7:   instantiated from '_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = std::unique_ptr<th>*, _BI2 = std::unique_ptr<th>*]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:978:4:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move_backward(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_deque.h:422:13:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move_backward(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:174:6:   instantiated from 'std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<th> >, std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::unique_ptr<th>, std::unique_ptr<th>&, std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:97:18:   instantiated from here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:208:19: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:513:7: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::_ConvertibleConcept<_From, _To>::__constraints() [with _From = std::unique_ptr<th>, _To = std::unique_ptr<th>]':
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:57:50:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::__function_requires() [with _Concept = __gnu_cxx::_ConvertibleConcept<std::unique_ptr<th>, std::unique_ptr<th> >]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:674:7:   instantiated from '_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = std::unique_ptr<th>*, _BI2 = std::unique_ptr<th>*]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:978:4:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move_backward(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_deque.h:422:13:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move_backward(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:174:6:   instantiated from 'std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<th> >, std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::unique_ptr<th>, std::unique_ptr<th>&, std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:97:18:   instantiated from here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:207:7: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:218:27: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::_OutputIteratorConcept<_Tp, _ValueT>::__constraints() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>*, _ValueT = std::unique_ptr<th>]':
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:57:50:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::__function_requires() [with _Concept = __gnu_cxx::_OutputIteratorConcept<std::unique_ptr<th>*, std::unique_ptr<th> >]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:501:7:   instantiated from '_OI std::move(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::unique_ptr<th>*, _OI = std::unique_ptr<th>*]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:939:4:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_deque.h:405:18:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:180:6:   instantiated from 'std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<th> >, std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::unique_ptr<th>, std::unique_ptr<th>&, std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:97:18:   instantiated from here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:208:19: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:462:7: error: used here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::_Mutable_ForwardIteratorConcept<_Tp>::__constraints() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>*]':
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:57:50:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::__function_requires() [with _Concept = __gnu_cxx::_Mutable_ForwardIteratorConcept<std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:512:7:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::_Mutable_BidirectionalIteratorConcept<_Tp>::__constraints() [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>*]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:57:50:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::__function_requires() [with _Concept = __gnu_cxx::_Mutable_BidirectionalIteratorConcept<std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:673:7:   instantiated from '_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = std::unique_ptr<th>*, _BI2 = std::unique_ptr<th>*]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:978:4:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move_backward(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, const _Tp&, const _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_deque.h:422:13:   instantiated from 'std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*> std::move_backward(std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>, std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Tp&, _Tp*>) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/deque.tcc:174:6:   instantiated from 'std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<th>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<th> >, std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::unique_ptr<th>, std::unique_ptr<th>&, std::unique_ptr<th>*>]'
/home/user/test/app/ato/main.cpp:97:18:   instantiated from here
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:208:19: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = th, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<th>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<th>]'
/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.04.01.00/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/boost_concept_check.h:488:7: error: used here
make: *** [/home/user/test/obj/main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your class is non-movable. I can understand that since the class has a `std::thread` you'd want to avoid the default copy behavior, but I don't see any reason that the class should be non-movable. If you enable the move construction and assignment [your code works fine](http://cpp.sh/3w53).

```
th(th const& other) = delete;
th(th && other) = default;
th& operator=(th const& other) = delete;
th& operator=(th &&) = default;
```

Also I'd adjust how you were constructing these objects to the following

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    deq.push_back(std::make_unique<th>(&progress[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Its still not compiling.../home/user/test/main.cpp:40:26: error: 'th& th::operator=(th&&)' cannot be defaulted

Comment: @mmmint Which compiler are you using? It must be a C++11 compiler to be able to create a default move assignment operator.

Comment: Its a crosscompiler from TI with experimental support of C++11 (C++03). Target: arm-arago-linux-gnueabi
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.3 20110311 (prerelease) (GCC)